# Test for comparing means of 3 measurements at 2 points in time

Tags: anova, spss, t-test

I want to compare the mean values of 3 measurements which were taken before and after a study. Measurements of specific vitamins were taken, e.g. vitamins C, D and iron, so I have 2 values for each - the baseline value, and the value at the end of the study.

Would it be appropriate to use an ANOVA/something else in this case, or 3 t-tests to look at the before/after effect on each vitamin level (I was worried about the error involved with the t-tests)?

Comment: Since you are analyzing mean values, do you also have the *n* or sample sizes for each as well as their standard deviations? Without that information and/or the raw data that went into the estimates of the means, you won't be able to do much.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have the raw data which I used to calculate the means and standard deviations. There was a total sample of 20 people (10 males, 10 females), however I have to compare the baseline/end of study values in the males and females separately eg. was there a significant difference in vitamin c values for males at the end of the study?

Comment: I have always used a ratio estimator for this sort of test as described on page 207 of Leslie Kish book *Survey Sampling*. Sorry, I don't know Latex and am unable to provide his formula for the estimator.